# Java JPA - Persisting Join Table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

Hy!

This drives me crazy for a few days now ... hope somebody can help me.

**Situation:**

I have a simple **datamodel** with three tables:

- Products (sa_s_prod)
- Components (sa_s_comp)
- CompProd (sa_l_compprod - which is the join table for Products and Components)

[image]

The join table (CompProd) has additional columns.

My (stripped) **entities** are as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_comp")
public class SComp implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int compId;
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
private String compName;
@Column(length = 50)
private String compDesc;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean compIsOnAvailability;
@Min(value = 0)
@Column(nullable = false)
private int compIndex;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Lkzs lkz;
@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date cdate;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String cuser;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "compgroupId", nullable = false)
private SCompGroup group;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LCompProd> products;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "transId", unique = true, nullable = true)
private STrans translation;

...

/**
 * Adds the given product to the list of assigned products for this
 * component.
 *
 * @param prod
 *            the product to be assigned
 * @return the component
 */
public void addProduct(SProd prod) {
if (this.products == null)
    this.products = new ArrayList<LCompProd>();
LCompProd compprod = new LCompProd(this, prod);
this.products.add(compprod);
compprod.setComponent(this);
}
```

### ....

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sa_s_prod")
public class SProd implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int prodId;
@NotNull
private Product.Type prodType;
@NotNull
private String prodName;
private String prodDesc;
private BigDecimal prodQuantityDef;
private Globals.Units prodUnitDef;
private Lkzs lkz;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "subcatId", nullable = false)
private SSubCat subcat;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "transId", unique = true)
private STrans translation;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<LCompProd> components;
```

### ....

```
@Entity
@IdClass(LCompProdId.class)
@Table(name = "sa_l_compprod")
public class LCompProd implements Serializable {

@Id
private int compId;
@Id
private int prodId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "compId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SComp component;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "prodId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private SProd product;

@NotNull
private Lkzs lkz;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date cdate;
private String cuser;
```

### ....

```
public class LCompProdId implements Serializable {

private int compId;
private int prodId;
....
```

With this code I can retrieve components and the associated products without problems. But **I can not persist to the join table** (CompProd). Even without cascading on doing this manualy with two independet persists.

The problem is that a foreign key constraint fails because the **primary key of the component (compId) is not set in the "join data object"** during persisting.

Perhaps it is the "normal" behaviour to set the primary/foreign key manualy, but I can't believe that hibernate is not able to handle this simple thing?! (Hope I'm right ;-)

I read a lot of articles and blogs, tried different approaches but still can't get this to work (in a way it should be implemented).

Any help appreciated. Thx.

PS: I'm using JPA2 (Hibernate).

Comment: I tried this with a additional Primary key in the join table and adjusted the entities. This works. But why can't combined Primary keys not be used as foreign keys or why they are not updated during persist? Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get your *compId* and *prodId* values on the *SComp* and *SProd* objects creations.

How do you propagate the generated ids to the *LCompProd* entity ? Are you sure the object you fetch the values from are managed entities ?

For example, if you create your objects with a [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)) call, the parameter does not become a managed entity. Therefore you should not get directly the generated Id. You get it with the result of the method call.

Comment: The IDs are propagated in the "addProduct"-method (e.g. this.component.getCompId()) - which is of course is 0 at this time, but should be set to a correct value (AutoIncrement) after persisting SComp?! All entities are managed. I don't use "merge" to persist object. (Even I didn't know that this works ;-)

Comment: If I understand well, you assign via the #addProduct(..) method before entites persist (so Id assignation => 0). But your Id is a primitive type, later increment won't be propagated as it is not an object

Comment: So the answer to the question is ... you have to do it with manually setting the id and persist in two steps?

Comment: I think so, as long as your Id is a primitive type. Another solution could be to use Integer as a type.